# Почему таблица обновляется не сразу?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть форма на которой так-же есть DataGridView. Я выполняю SQL запрос по нажатию кнопки и вызываю обновление этой самой таблицы. Вот код

```
private void btUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cbPosition.Checked) {
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(tbID.Text);
            string query = "UPDATE TDoljnost SET НаименованиеДолжности = '" + tbPosition.Text + "' WHERE IDДолжности = " + key;
            OleDbCommand dbCommand = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
            dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            this.tDoljnostTableAdapter.Fill(this.workDataSet.TDoljnost);
        }
    }
```

Однако, в самой программе таблица обновляется только при следующем клике по кнопке, но при этом в БД все с первого раза работает

Вот полный файл с кодом(внутри по пути dbForm\bin\Debug файл БД work.mdb) [Файл с проектом](https://dl.uploadgram.me/60acf5550995ah)

Comment: datagridview1.Update(); datagridview1.Refresh(); - не работают?

Comment: @Blackmeser Нет, увы такой способ не работает

Comment: Смотрите было ли изменение в том объекте что подключаете к таблице, если нет - делайте перезапрос.

Comment: @Blackmeser в том то и суть что в таблице все меняется корректно, с первого раза. При повторном запросе(нажатии) и если данные изменились, то в таблице меняются на новые, а вот в форме меняются на те, что обновлял до этого